# My Android Studio project keeps running my old project/application

Tags: android, android-studio

I had an Android Studio project I created. The project was named App2-1. After I was done with that project I wanted to move onto my next project named App2-2 that is based off of App2-1. I copied and pasted the directory containing my project "App2-1" and named the new directory "App2-2". Then I opened up the directory using open project in Android Studio. No errors or anything. I made a whole bunch of changes and then I ran the app and it keeps opening my old app. Almost like it has a reference to it or something. Ideas?

Things I've tried:

- Restarting Android Studio
- Invalidating caches/Restart in AS
- Restarted my emulator
- Uninstalled my app from emulator/Clean install
- Tried a physical device

I'm guessing my workflow of creating a new project based on an old project was incorrect. Appreciate any tips.

Comment: Have you tried doing a clean and then rebuild from Android Studio. It might be the build files were also copied and it hasn't realised its changed so its running the old APK still, doing a clean and rebuild will cause all the build stuff to be removed and everything rebuilt from scratch

Comment: Yeah, I did try that. Forgot to mention it in the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would make a copy of the project in a new folder and in this copy delete the following;

- .iml file
- .gradle folder
- .idea folder
- build folder

then open Android Studio and select 'File > Import Project...' and select the new projects settings.gradle file and click 'open'

You might have to check the dependencies and re-build but hopefully this should set things up in AS from scratch.

Comment: Heh. What do you know. I had a App2-1.iml file and App2-2.iml file. I deleted that first, then re-opened and everything worked fine. Ideas?

Comment: Yeah that file holds all Android Studio config as far as I know so probably got created when you opened for the second time with the renamed dir. worth an up vote for me? :-)

Comment: Yes, and thanks for the help. Let me know if you find an actual answer for what an iml is by any chance. Sure it's only a google search away, but I'm still curious to why it defaulted to a different iml file.

Comment: I was having problems a while ago with the wrong app name in the windows title bar, I looked everywhere and eventually found that the name comes from an iml file.

Answer (score 2):

For me, 'Gradle -> Tasks -> other -> clean' worked.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a new functionality. For me worked:

`File` -> `Invalidate Caches / Restart` -> `Invalidate and Restart`

Answer (score 1):

Tools > AVD manager > click the downward arrow next to your emulator > cold boot now

This should fix all of emulator problems.

Comment: As well, you can do Tools > AVD Manger > Wipe Data. That is if you do not have another project that is dependent upon that particular AVD Device.

Answer (score 0):

For me using AVD Manager -> Actions -> Wipe data made it work.

Answer (score 0):

For me **Build -> Clean project**, and then **Rebuild project** worked